# fields_for in the show view, nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

While I'm learning rails want to try to imitate some stackoverflow features. Particulary I'm interested in Q&A system when Question has many Answers and Comment belongs to Question and Answer. So, I started from associations and nested attributes. Learning source for nested attributes is railcast.com and there Ryan is adding forms(Question,Answer) to new.html.erb(Survey), however I would like to add to show.html.erb. When I do that It looks fine, unless I post something. After first submit answer, question show renders posted answer, empty form for answer and populated with text answer form. So overall I have answer and two forms(one empty another with text). How can I make render only empty form for answer?

show.html.erb

```
 @question.answers.each do |answer|
  answer.body
 end

 form_for @question do |f|
  f.fields_for :answers do |builder|
  builder.text_area :body
 end
  f.submit
 end
```

question.rb

```
 has_many :answers
 accept_nested_attributes_for :answer
 accept_nested_attributes_for :comment
```

answer.rb

```
 belongs_to :question
 accept_nested_attributes_for :comment
```

comment.rb

```
 belongs_to :answer
 belongs_to :question
```

questions_controller.rb

```
 def show
 @question = Question.find(params[:id])
 @question.answers.build
 end
```

Comment: try replacing `fields_for` line with `f.fields_for :answers, @question.answers.build do |builder|`

Answer (score 2):

In Michał Szyndel case rails most likely will give you an error can't mass-assign attributes answer. Like Manoj Monga suggested just try to make like that:

```
form_for @question do |f|
  f.fields_for :answers, @question.answers.build do |builder|
  builder.text_area :body
end
   f.submit
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so let's see what's going on in your code.
First, in the controller, you're finding a Question object

```
@question = Question.find(params[:id])
```

and building an association for one new/empty answer

```
@question.answers.build
```

so there should be new answer object attached to @question

Then in a view you first display all existing questions

```
@question.answers.each do |answer|
  answer.body
end
```

and it works ok (for now, I'll show you how to break it in a while)
and then display a form for what you expect to be a new answer you initialized in controller (`@question.answers.build`)

So why is there a form for existing answer? What Rails really does is it takes all answers associated with @question and build a form for EACH of them. And, since you added one answer theres ... two! One existing and one just initialized with `@question.answers.build`

So, how to fix this code? Do following

```
@question.answers.select(&:persisted?).each do |answer|
  answer.body
end
```

to display ONLY answers saved to the database (try adding a content length validation to Answer and see what happens if you try to save an invalid one)

And for the form simply do

```
f.fields_for Answer.new do |builder|
```

to always have just one answer form.